# How to run protractor end to end tests in docker container?

Tags: docker, protractor, docker-container

I am beginner to docker container.I just started to run protractor end to end test in docker container. My application is in angular 2 typescript. I tried to figure out how to configure docker and found out image from the docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/caltha/protractor/ and downloaded this image in my virtual machine. I used this command and gave my test location folder.The container terminated automatically. I dont see any output directory generated or neither end tests are executed.

> docker pull caltha/protractor
>
> docker run --rm -v /home/ubuntu/git/Test/dashboard/test:/project
> caltha/protractor

```
//protractor.conf.js
    exports.config = {
      framework: 'jasmine2',    
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      specs: ['test/e2e/menu.js'],
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox', 
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/dashboard/#/',
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
       showColors: true,
     },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to search for the output file as the website says?

> The output of supervisord visible on the console is not interesting in most circumstances. You should check target/supervsor.out file to see the output of Protractor. Dispalying the file in an Unix terminal using cat is recommended over opening it using an editor because the file contains ANSI escape sequences.

Also you can leave the docker open for your testing instead opening and closing when executed the command. This way you could see the actual errors in console. 
Try:

```
CONTAINER=$(docker run -d -v /home/ubuntu/git/Test/dashboard/test:/project --env MANUAL=yes caltha/protractor)
docker exec -ti $CONTAINER sudo -i -u node bash
```

From: [Caltha/protractor website](https://hub.docker.com/r/caltha/protractor/)

**EDIT:**

Using the following command you it should open in terminal the docker container with your project:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/ubuntu/git/Test/dashboard/test:/project --privileged caltha/protractor bash
```

Then you just need to run the protractor as you do locally

```
protractor protractor.conf.js
```

(if protractor has been exposed to the path this should work.. if not write a comment)

Comment: With this command execution - `CONTAINER=$(docker run -d -v /home/ubuntu/git/Test/dashboard/test:/project --env MANUAL=yes caltha/protractor)
docker exec -ti $CONTAINER sudo -i -u node bash` I get this error `rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not started`

Comment: No I could not find that file. These are the files listed in root `bin   etc   lib32   media  proc     run   supervisord.log  tmp
boot  home  lib64   mnt    project  sbin  supervisord.pid  usr
dev   lib   libx32  opt    root     srv   sys     var`

Comment: I've found that you could be using an old docker version, maybe the image you are trying to use is not the one you are looking for.
Could you run this? "docker run -it --rm alpine sh" and "docker ps" shows something?

Comment: docker version :1.12.6 and after running "docker ps" it shows alpine image and container id etc.

Comment: docker run -it --rm -v /home/ubuntu/git/Test/dashboard/test:/project --privileged caltha/protractor bash

Comment: The above command will execute and opens the container terminal. Do I need to run protractor.conf.js in this container? `docker run -it --rm -v /home/ubuntu/git/Test/dashboard/test:/project --privileged caltha/protractor bash
root@9d6b82591b2a:/# protractor protractor.conf.js`

Comment: Yes, the above command is used for opening the docker so you can send commands to his terminal. Try to use protractor (if you can find the executable) to run the tests, and share the results :)

Comment: No it did not work..I tried to execute with this command protractor protractor.conf.js in docker terminal where the test project resides but got  `Error : Cannot find module '/protractor.conf.js'`

Comment: Could you list "ls" the directory? is protractor working inside docker? "protractor --version"